# Nylon brush in a Western?

Tags: plot-explanation, props, the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly

[image]

You tell me.  Is that a Nylon brush in that hand?  The movie this comes from was set in 1865.  I know... I know.  Endless loops of gaffs and goofs.  No.  Not looking for trouble.

Those are Clint's hands.  The Good, the Bad, and the Ugly.  I thought the production was better than to succumb to a prop error like that.  Or... was there a brush like that back then?  Can anyone restore my faith in Sergio Leone or did he just toss Mr. Eastwood that cleaning brush out of his personal gun cleaning kit because it just looked better in the scene?

Answer (score 9):

It looks a bit like this picture:
[image]

The material is steel wire ([Original description in (German)](http://www.frey-pinsel.de/shop/zylinderbuersten/zylinderbuersten-sorte-542)  is *Gedreht, **Stahldraht**, mit Öse.*).

So, it doesn't need to be Nylon.

---

I found also a picture from a [German museum](http://www.museen-sh.de/Objekt/DE-MUS-150714/lido/978): 
[image]

The brush is from 19. century.
The material for the brush is bristle, but if you change the color it may be the same as in the film. (The brush of the picture is larger, it is a brush for a cannon)

Comment: They could have also made the bristles out of brass as well. They still make those today ... doesn't have to be nylon, that's for sure.

Comment: Do you know when they first started making the top brush you presented?  And I agree... it could most definitely be black-tinted steel bristles.  The larger, older one would have been the inspiration for the smaller design... just wondering if the smaller would would have existed in 1865.

Comment: I looked for this information, but was not successful. So I presented the results I found. I was also impressed by [Napoleons Toothbrush](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Napoleon’s_toothbrush,_c_1795._(9660576547).jpg) - but that's not round ;)